# NSWindow positioning

Tags: swift, macos

I'm the author of a [Hearthstone tracker](https://github.com/bmichotte/HSTracker), and I have to move several `NSWindow` over Hearthstone window.

I get the frame of Hearthstone using `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`.
Then, I have to move my windows at some positions relative to Hearthstone.

[image: HSTracker overlays]
The red arrows are over opponent cards, green arrow is over turn button and blue arrows are at the left and right of the window.

My actual screen setup is the following :

[image: Screen setup]

which gives me the following frames

```
// screen 1 : {x 0 y 0 w 1.440 h 900}
// screen 2 : {x 1.440 y -180 w 1.920 h 1.080}
```

To place the opponent tracker (the left frame) at the right position, which is the most simple case, I use `{x 0 y somepadding w 185 h hearthstoneHeight - somepadding}` and get the correct frame with this

```
func relativeFrame(frame: NSRect) -> NSRect {
    var relative = frame
    relative.origin.x = NSMinX(hearthstoneFrame) + NSMinX(frame)
    relative.origin.y = NSMinY(hearthstoneFrame) + NSMinY(frame)

    return relative
}
```

The right tracker is placed using `{x hearthstoneWidth - trackerWidth, ...}`

For other overlays, I used my current (Hearthstone) resolution to place them and them calculate them using a simple math

```
x = x / 1404.0 * NSWidth(hearthstoneFrame)
y = y / 840.0 * NSHeight(hearthstoneFrame)
```

This works pretty well. Except if I use my second screen. In this case, the frames seems to be correct, but the position of the window is not good.

Here is a screenshot of a debug window with `{x 0 y 0 w hearthstoneWidth h hearthsoneHeight }`. If I compare the frames of Hearthstone and my overlay, they are identical.
[image: Debug overlay]

The complete function is the following (I'm in a "static class", I only show revelant code). I guess I'm missing something in the calculation but I can't find what.

```
class frameRelative {
   static var hearthstoneFrame = NSZeroRect
   static func findHearthstoneFrame() {
       let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .ExcludeDesktopElements)
       let windowListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
       if let info = (windowListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]])?
           .filter({
              !$0.filter({ $0.0 == "kCGWindowName" && $0.1 as? String == "Hearthstone" }).isEmpty
            })
            .first {
              var rect = NSRect()
              let bounds = info["kCGWindowBounds"] as! CFDictionary
              CGRectMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation(bounds, &rect)
              rect.size.height -= titleBarHeight // remove the 22px from the title
              hearthstoneFrame = rect
       }
  }

  static func frameRelative(frame: NSRect, _ isRelative: Bool = false) -> NSRect {
      var relative = frame
      var pointX = NSMinX(relative)
      var pointY = NSMinY(relative)

      if isRelative {
          pointX = pointX / 1404.0 * NSWidth(hearthstoneFrame)
          pointY = pointY / 840.0 * NSHeight(hearthstoneFrame)
      }

      let x: CGFloat = NSMinX(hearthstoneFrame) + pointX
      let y = NSMinY(hearthstoneFrame) + pointY

      relative.origin = NSMakePoint(x, y)
      return relative
  }
}

// somewhere here
let frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, hearthstoneWidth, hearthstoneHeight)
let relativeFrame = SizeHelper.frameRelative(frame)
myWindow.setFrame(relativeFrame, display: true)
```

Any help will be appreciate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually solved this issue so I decided to post the answer to close this thread... and maybe if someone face the same issue one day.

The solution was to substract the *max y* from the *first screen* with the *max y* of the Hearthstone window.

The final code of `findHearthstoneFrame` is

```
static func findHearthstoneFrame() {
   let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .ExcludeDesktopElements)
        let windowListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
        if let info = (windowListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]])?.filter({
            !$0.filter({ $0.0 == "kCGWindowName"
                && $0.1 as? String == "Hearthstone" }).isEmpty
        }).first {
            if let id = info["kCGWindowNumber"] as? Int {
                self.windowId = CGWindowID(id)
            }
            var rect = NSRect()
            let bounds = info["kCGWindowBounds"] as! CFDictionary
            CGRectMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation(bounds, &rect)

            if let screen = NSScreen.screens()?.first {
                rect.origin.y = NSMaxY(screen.frame) - NSMaxY(rect)
            }

            self._frame = rect
        }
 }
```

And the `frameRelative` is

```
static let BaseWidth: CGFloat = 1440.0
static let BaseHeight: CGFloat = 922.0
var scaleX: CGFloat {
    return NSWidth(_frame) / SizeHelper.BaseWidth
}

var scaleY: CGFloat {
    // 22 is the height of the title bar
    return (NSHeight(_frame) - 22) / SizeHelper.BaseHeight
}
func frameRelative(frame: NSRect, relative: Bool = true) -> NSRect {
    var pointX = NSMinX(frame)
    var pointY = NSMinY(frame)
    let width = NSWidth(frame)
    let height = NSHeight(frame)

    if relative {
        pointX = pointX * scaleX
        pointY = pointY * scaleY
    }

    let x: CGFloat = NSMinX(self.frame) + pointX
    let y: CGFloat = NSMinY(self.frame) + pointY

    let relativeFrame = NSRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    return relativeFrame
}
```